# Reactive ggplot with reactive data frame in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is a follow on post to one I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626299/applying-a-function-which-takes-in-values-and-return-the-results-from-a-data-fra/62626572#62626572). The original question required the user to input some values into some text boxes/numeric boxes compute some function and then display the result in a data frame.
It can be computed using the following R code (which also includes the `ggplot2` plot I would also like to add).

R Code:

```
someFunction <- function(S, K, type){
  
  # call option
  if(type=="C"){
    d1 <- S/K
    value <- S*pnorm(d1) - K*pnorm(d1)
    return(value)}
  
  # put option
  if(type=="P"){
    d1 <- S*K
    value <-  (K*pnorm(d1) - S*pnorm(d1))
    return(value)}
}


SInput <- 20
KInput <- 25
Seq <- seq(from = KInput - 1, to = KInput + 1, by = 0.25)

C <- someFunction(
  S = SInput,
  K = Seq,                                                  
  type = "C"
)

P <- someFunction(
  S = SInput,
  K = Seq,
  type = "P"
)

df <- data.frame(C, P, Seq)         # create the data frame for the ggplot and Shiny output


df %>%                              # plot that data frame
  ggplot(aes(x = Seq)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = C)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = P))
```

I want to create the same `ggplot` - reactive plot in Shiny. The Shiny code I have is the following.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

#######################################################################
############################### Functions #############################

someFunction <- function(S, K, type){
    
    # call option
    if(type=="C"){
        d1 <- S/K
        value <- S*pnorm(d1) - K*pnorm(d1)
        return(value)}
    
    # put option
    if(type=="P"){
        d1 <- S*K
        value <-  (K*pnorm(d1) - S*pnorm(d1))
        return(value)}
}


############################### Header ###############################
header <- dashboardHeader()

#######################################################################
############################### Sidebar ###############################
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

#######################################################################
############################### Body ##################################

body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
        numericInput("SInput", "Input S:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
        numericInput("KInput", "Input K:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
        tableOutput("S_K_Output")
    )
)

#######################################################################

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

#######################################################################

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$S_K_Output <- renderTable({
        Seq <- seq(from = input$KInput - 1, to = input$KInput + 1, by = 0.25)    # create a sequence going from K-1 to K+1
        C <- someFunction(
            S = input$SInput,
            K = Seq,                                                    # Apply this sequence to the function
            type = "C"
        )
        P <- someFunction(
            S = input$SInput,
            K = Seq,
            type = "P"
        )
        data.frame(C, P, Seq)                                               # Extract the results and put side-by-side 
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The above Shiny code works for producing the table but I also want to include the plot. I am finding it difficult since the above code outputs the results into a `renderTable({})` function (i.e. returning a HTML table and simply adding the `ggplot` code doesn't work.)

I have tried `renderPlot` and pasting all the above code again from `renderTable` into the same function but I don't want to repeat unnecessary calculations. So my question is how can I export the `data.frame(C, P, Seq)` into a `ggplot2` graphic from two different `renderTable` and `renderPlot`? I can add the `tablePlot` just under the `tableOutput` in the `fluidPage` part of the code but I am not able to get results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start thinking about dependency and removing redundancy. That is, if you are creating data of some sort and you even *think* that it will be used by more than one "thing", then break it out into "reactive data", and then depend on it in multiple locations.

Oh, and if you want to show a plot, you need to use `plotOutput`.

Changes from your previous code:

- if you want a plot, you need to add a `plotOutput`;
- convert the code in your `renderTable` into a `reactive` block that *just calculates data*, it does nothing to consider how to show or filter it;
- re-add the `renderTable` to deal with the data as created in the previously-mentioned block;
- add `renderPlot` (paired with `plotOutput`); and finally
- added `req(mydata())` to the plot output, so that if the data is empty or `NULL` (for whatever reason), then the plotting code will not fire. See `?req` if you have questions about this, or its companion functions `validate` and `need`.

Note that when using reactive data, you must call it like a function. So the `mydata` reactive data block makes its data available to other reactive components when called as `mydata()`. Do not try to "view" `mydata` (without the parens), it does nothing for you.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

#######################################################################
############################### Functions #############################

someFunction <- function(S, K, type){
    
    # call option
    if(type=="C"){
        d1 <- S/K
        value <- S*pnorm(d1) - K*pnorm(d1)
        return(value)}
    
    # put option
    if(type=="P"){
        d1 <- S*K
        value <-  (K*pnorm(d1) - S*pnorm(d1))
        return(value)}
}


############################### Header ###############################
header <- dashboardHeader()

#######################################################################
############################### Sidebar ###############################
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

#######################################################################
############################### Body ##################################

body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
        numericInput("SInput", "Input S:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
        numericInput("KInput", "Input K:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
        tableOutput("S_K_Output"),
        plotOutput("Plot_Output")
    )
)

#######################################################################

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

#######################################################################

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- reactive({
    Seq <- seq(from = input$KInput - 1, to = input$KInput + 1, by = 0.25)    # create a sequence going from K-1 to K+1
    C <- someFunction(
      S = input$SInput,
      K = Seq,                                                    # Apply this sequence to the function
      type = "C"
    )
    P <- someFunction(
      S = input$SInput,
      K = Seq,
      type = "P"
    )
    data.frame(C, P, Seq)                                               # Extract the results and put side-by-side 
  })
  output$S_K_Output <- renderTable({ mydata() })
  output$Plot_Output <- renderPlot({
    req(mydata())
    # plot that data frame
    ggplot(mydata(), aes(x = Seq)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = C)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = P))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just curious (and my apologies for being candid), have you gone through any of the tutorials at https://shiny.rstudio.com? Some of your code suggests that you are still learning the concepts of reactivity/dependency. I know I often need to learn by trying/break/fixing/doing, so I can relate to the workflow, but much of this is covered (for instance) in their lessons on reactivity ([written](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) and [video](https://vimeo.com/rstudioinc/review/131218530/212d8a5a7a/#t=47m25s)).

Comment: Yes, I am currently going through the tutorials. I have not gone through the written tutorials that you pointed out but I have gone through the video and a few other tutorials online. I just wanted to get started with my own mini project and I have learned more from your two answers on reactivity than I have done from the courses I was taking, so thank you for that. I will check out the written tutorials as they look very informative.

Comment: Glad this helps, keep 'em coming.